# Choose 3 letters.

Tags: combinatorics, multisets

Find in how many ways an arrangement of $3$ letters can be made from the $26$ different letters of the alphabet if any letter may be used once, twice or thrice. How many of these arrangements will not contain not more than two different letters?

Examples of selections are $\{a,a,a\}$, $\{a,b,b\}$, $\{a,b,c\}$. The first part tells us to count all possible things. The second part says us to count those only $1$st and $2$nd of the examples given above, which means that the chosen set should not have $3$ different letters.

Please help me solve this question.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please rephrase the second part? It's pretty unclear.

Comment: For the first part, you should break it down into cases based on repitition (i.e. whether a letter might be used once, twice or thrice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total number of arrangements is $26^3$

The number of arrangements with $3$ different letters is $\binom{26}{3}\cdot3!$

The number of arrangements with no more than $2$ different letters is therefore $26^3-\binom{26}{3}\cdot3!$

Comment: that gives answer as 1975

Comment: @ghaprameya: So?

Comment: 1975 was a good year.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: You were born?

Comment: No, I'm significantly older than that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: LOL, so what was good about it?

Comment: Game 6 of the World Series. http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/BOS/BOS197510210.shtml

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Game $5$ between Golden State and Portland sounds more interesting IMO... But then again, I know nothing about Baseball...

Comment: Come Back, bark manos Why did you multiply 3! there

Comment: @ghaprameya: In order to permute the letters.

Comment: Well you could have written **P(26,3)**

Comment: @ghaprameya: We could have also written $26\cdot25\cdot24$ or $\dfrac{26!}{23!}$... What's your point?